# Is "You can invite the user to the workspace with the admin role." grammatically correct?

Tags: prepositions

The following sentence looks awkward to me:

*You can invite the user to the workspace with the admin role.*

I think a good way to put it should be:

*You can invite the user to the workspace and assign the admin role to the user.*

Comment: Those two mean different things to me.  It’s now unclear what it’s supposed to mean.

Comment: Probably you need admin privileges to do invitations to the workspace.

Comment: How about this: *You can invite the user to the workspace with the workspace-operator role*. I think the sentence should be changed to *You can invite the user to the workspace and assign the workspace-operator role to the user*.

Comment: It is supposed to mean "Invite a user to the workspace and assign a role such as admin or operator to the user so that the user can work as an administrator or operator in the workspace".

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is ungrammatical. The second sentence is fine but the sense of it seems wrong. This is because admin roles are generally sensitive and not usually assignable to just any user. I'd suggest:

> You can invite a user to the workspace and you are allowed to assign her or him the admin role.

Comment: The first is not ungrammatical.  It can be taken to mean: “Using the admin role, you can invite the user to the workspace.”  Or it could mean: “You can invite the user to the workspace that has the admin role.”

Comment: @Jim: If the OP regarded this sentence as you first put it, then it would be grammatically correct. But he wants it to be understood in the sense of his second sentence, and then the sentence doesn't work semantically/grammatically. This is how I took it and why I said it isn't grammatically correct.